# Badges for private beta site aren't shown in the network profile

Tags: bug, badges, ios-app, private-beta, communities-list

In the list of accounts on my network profile, the badges for the new [Augur Stack Exchange site](https://augur.stackexchange.com/) aren't shown:

[image]

It should've shown [8 bronze badges](https://augur.stackexchange.com/users/35/glorfindel), I had those for a couple of days so it's not likely to be a caching issue. At the time of posting this question, Augur.SE was still in **private beta**. This seems to be the core issue; 6-8 months later, the badges for Augur.SE (now in public beta) *are* shown but for the new private beta [Quantum Computing](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/) they again aren't.

I'm running v1.6.6.2 on an iPhone 7 Plus, iOS 10.3.3.